# k8s deploy job to run once, and only when deployment change

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

we have a job that setup the DB views.

This job should run once deployed, and only if someone will do any changes to the code (which will cause to CD process to redeploy)
we do not want the job to run on other corn scheduling.
we use helm.
how should we define such job?

Comment: As a [hook](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/)?

Comment: it will work, but AFAIK hook good for run something else, but here we want to run the job itself once it's deployed or deployment rolled.
is there some more OOB k8s  solution